# Create LINQ expression with two aggregate operators

Tags: c#, sql, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [`SELECT MIN(ZoneMin), MAX(ZoneMin) FROM Plant` as LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672239/select-minzonemin-maxzonemin-from-plant-as-linq-to-sql)

I'm trying to create a LINQ expression with two aggregate operators.

How should the LINQ expression be for the following SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 PlayerId, Max(Score) AS Score, Min(Name) AS Name FROM Scores
GROUP BY PlayerId
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

I need as result a list of "Scores" objects.

thanks