# Select Count(*), Max(Field1), Min(Field1)

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [`SELECT MIN(ZoneMin), MAX(ZoneMin) FROM Plant` as LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672239/select-minzonemin-maxzonemin-from-plant-as-linq-to-sql)

I am having a hard time trying to convert the following SQL query into Linq.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS Qty, 
  MAX(Field1) AS MinValue, 
  MIN(Field1) AS MaxValue,
  SUM(Field2) AS TotalValue
FROM 
  Table1
WHERE
  FieldTypeID = 1
```

I do realize that I could perform 4 linq expressions to get each part, but I would rather not hit the server 4 times if possible.