# Is Aggregate fatally flawed because each into clause is executed separately?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, aggregate-functions, aggregate

*Is VB.NET's `Aggregate` query fatally flawed when used as the first (outer) clause of a Linq expression with multiple `Into` clauses because each `Into` clause is executed separately?*

The "obvious" answer to [`SELECT MIN(ZoneMin), MAX(ZoneMin) FROM Plant` in LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4672239/256431) is

```vb
Dim limits = Aggregate p In Plants Select p.ZoneMin Into Min(), Max()
```

However, this answer actually retrieves each of `Min` and `Max` (and if you include other aggregate functions like `Count` and `Average`) in *separate* SQL queries.  This can be easily seen in LINQPad.

Is there a transaction (or something else making these queries atomic) not shown by LINQPad, or is this a race condition waiting to happen? (And so you have to do the tricks shown in the answer to the above question to force a single query that returns multiple aggregates.)

In summary, is there a LINQ-to-SQL query using `Aggregate` that returns multiple aggregate functions in a single (or at least "atomic") query?

<sub>(I also say "obvious" because the obvious answer to me, `Aggregate p In Plants Into Min(p.ZoneMin), Max(p.ZoneMin)`, actually retrieves the whole table twice, even when optimised, and then uses the Linq-to-Entities `Min` and `Max` to obtain the result :-( )</sub>

<sub>I thought `Aggregate` wasn't VB-specific, but it looks like C# does not have this query expression, so I've changed the [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) to [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net).</sub>

Comment: You might be able to verify if the queries are in a transaction by tracing the SQL server itself, it should show it (but I'm not 100% sure about it). If performance is not a prime concern, however, you're better off reading the whole dataset and aggregating afterwards (basically, working on a snapshot of the data).

Comment: Note that that's what I hoped my original `Into Min(p.ZoneMin)` query would optimise to, seeing as the SQL part of the query is now the same. Perhaps the JITter might be able to still see that, but LINQPad's /o+ didn't.

Comment: And while you're only aggregating with functions that SQL supports it will be preferable to do the "grouping by a constant trick" to get the database to do the aggregation.

Comment: It appears that there may be some bugs in the L2S implementation. See http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2008/05/21/vb-net-beware-of-the-aggregate-keyword.aspx

Comment: @JimWooley: If you up that comment to an answer, I'll upvote it (just not straight away because it doesn't answer _this_ question) and possibly accept it as the answer unless someone identifies a way to get `Aggregate` to combine all the queries into a single SQL request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my broader question: is `Aggregate` broken for producing separate SQL queries without transactions?

All of LINQ can cause that if you don't carefully adjust your queries to only result in a single `SELECT`, and that may not be possible, without "giving up", retrieving a larger result in a single query and then using Linq-to-Objects to aggregate or otherwise manipulate the data. [This 'query'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12689544/256431) for example.

So it is, in general, up to the programmer to ensure transactions are added around LINQ queries that may cause multiple queries. We just need to know for sure which LINQ queries may transform into multiple SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't use the Aggregate keyword, you can do multiple functions in a single query using the following syntax:

```
Dim query = From book In books _
    Group By key = book.Subject Into Group _
    Select id = key, _
        BookCount = Group.Count, _
        TotalPrice = Group.Sum(Function(_book) _book.Price), _
        LowPrice = Group.Min(Function(_book) _book.Price), _
        HighPrice = Group.Max(Function(_book) _book.Price), _
        AveragePrice = Group.Average(Function(_book) _book.Price)
```

There does appear to be an issue with the Aggregate clause implementation though. Consider the following query from Northwind:

```
Aggregate o in Orders
into Sum(o.Freight),
Average(o.Freight),
Max(o.Freight)
```

This issues 3 database requests. The first two perform separate aggregate clauses. The third pulls the entire table back to the client and performs the Max on the client through Linq to Objects.

Comment: Yeah, and if you change it to `Group By key = 0 Into Group` (and drop the unneeded `id = key,`) you get the "grouping by a constant" trick described in the answer to the question I've referred to, allowing aggregates over the whole table.

Comment: In my sample, I do want the grouping. If you want it over the whole table, then your constant trick works fine.

Comment: I *think* your latter point is related to the type `Freight` is seen to be, and for some reason Linq is of the opinion SQL's `MAX` could return a different value to what it thinks `Max` should return. But the _3 __separate__ database requests_ is what my question is concerned with.

Comment: Also note your `Freight` query may somehow be related to the issue Frans Bouma reports in his blog linked to by Jim Wooley.

Comment: Um, yeah. I'm a little familiar with those posts ;-) My [post](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Aggregate-clause-issues) is in part a reminder to the teams that it is still an issue.

Comment: Whoops, yeah I missed you're the same person :-)